# Why does netbeans keep telling me that my variables are not being used?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a new Java programmer. I was trying to make a program that would add two numbers that the user had to input. For some reason Netbeans keeps telling me that my variables are not being used.

```
package Calculator;

import java.util.Scanner; 


public class Calculator {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        double numOne;
        double numTwo;
        double sum;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the first number: ");
        numOne = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
        numTwo = in.nextDouble();
       //code unfinished.

   }

}
```

Comment: It just gives you warnings that you have declared some variable(s) but haven't used it for any purpose. Please do not confuse with error and warning. Once you use the variables (probably add them) then the warning would go. Hint- `sum = numOne + numTwo; System.out.println(sum);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening for different reasons.

For variables `numOne` and `numTwo`, you are writing to them in `numOne = in.nextDouble();` but you never read that value again. In other words, if your program was finished (I know it isn't), those variables would be pointless as you never perform any calculations on them.

As others have pointed out, the `sum` variable has not been assigned a value nor used. This variable declaration is unnecessary.

While you are writing your code, you can safely ignore this warnings. However, if you are finished writing your class and you still have these warnings, you should go back and make sure you are actually using your variables. If you never use a variable that you define and you consider your class complete, you should be able to safely delete that variable reference without any adverse effects (although it's always good practice to be careful with those sorts of things).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason NetBeans is telling you so is because you haven't actually used them yet. :) Just reading them in is an indicator to NetBeans that you aren't actually doing anything meaningful with the variables.

Try using them in some calculations or printing them out.